# Closed and exact forms on Fibers of a vector bundle

Tags: differential-geometry

Assume I am given a closed 2-form $\alpha$ on the tangent bundle $\pi\colon TM\to M$, which enjoys the following property: for each pair of vertical vector fields $V_1,V_2$ we have $\alpha(V_1,V_2)=0$. By vertical, I mean the following: $V$ is vertical if it is tangent to the fibers of $\pi$, i.e. if for each $y\in M$ we have $T\pi(V_y)=0$; in other words, $V$ is $\pi$-related to $0$. The question is whether there exists locally a function $F$ such that for any vertical vector field $V$ one has $dF(V)=\phi(V)$, where $\phi$ is such that $d\phi=\alpha$ (we define $\phi$ this way). Note that I am only asking for this property on vertical vector fields $V$ (otherwise, such an $F$ need not exist). My intuition is that such an $F$ exists. All objects are smooth, and so should be the sought-for $F$.

My reasoning: $\alpha$ is closed, so we may choose a coordinate patch $U\subset M$ in the form of a ball and there exists a 1-form $\phi$ on $TU$ s.t. $\alpha=d\phi$. Moreover, if we write $I_y=\pi^{-1}(y)$ for the fiber over $y\in M$, and $i_y\colon I_y\to TM$ for its inclusion, one may easily check that $i_y^*\phi$ is closed, precisely because $d\phi=\alpha$ annihilates vertical vectors (**EDIT**: Rather, $d\phi=\alpha$ vanishes on two vertical vectors). Since $I_y$ is a vector space, this means that there exists a function $F_y\colon I_y\to\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $dF_y=i_y^*\phi$ ($F_y$ is defined up to a constant $c_y$). But ... how can I define $F$ and show that it is smooth? If one defines $F(x,v):=F_x(v)$ it is first not clear which $F_x$ to choose in each case (there is a $c_x$ to fix for each $x$, to start with) and whether the result is smooth (in $x$). One expects $F$ to be defined up to some constant on the fibers.

For completeness I include the same argument in coordinates. Choose $(x^i,v^i)$ coordinates in $TU$ and write $\phi=A_i(x^i,v^i)dx^i+B_i(x^i,v^i)dv^i$, so that $i_y^*\phi=B_i(x^i=y^i,v^i)dv^i$. Our $F\colon TU\to\mathbb{R}$ should satisfy $$\{\partial_{v^1}F(x^i,v^i)=B_1(x^i,v^i),\dots,\partial_{v^n}F(x^i,v^i)=B_n(x^i,v^i)\}$$ and some initial condition, say $F(x^i,v^i=0)=0$ (or some other smooth $\psi(x^i)$). Here we know that all $B_i$ are smooth (on both $x$ and $v$) and satisfy the closeness integrability condition $\partial_{v^1}B_2=\partial_{v^2}B_1$, etc. If we look at the system of PDEs, and thinking of $x^i$ as parameters, we do know that a solution exists (which will be smooth on the $v^i$). But, again, I can't see how to prove smoothness in the $x^i$.

I have not been able to find any helpful reference. I am aware of some results which deal with families of forms depending on parameters, but I just can't put my hands on the right one. Any help or reference is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I didn’t read carefully, but to say $\alpha$ annihilates vertical vectors is to say $\alpha(V,\cdot)=0$ for any vertical $V$. I didn’t proceed further in your post. Your condition says, then, that locally $\alpha$ has exactly one fiber covector, rather than none.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Thanks for your remark. It was indeed wrongly phrased, for I meant $\alpha$ vanishes on pairs of vertical vectors (as stated in the first paragraph). Locally, $\alpha$ will be missing any $dv^i\wedge dv^j$ terms. I have edited the question.